# Geometrical Interpretation of Cauchy Riemann equations?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Differentiation has an obvious geometric interpretation, and the Cauchy Riemann equations are closely linked with differentiation.

Do the Cauchy Riemann equations have a geometric interpretation?

Comment: @YvesDaoust What's an "iso curve" and what's an "orthogonal pencil"?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry, I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. Could you please expand on your comment? This is my first complex analysis course and my third course in calculus so I don't know a lot.

Comment: You should read *Visual Complex Analysis* by Tristan Needham.

Answer (score 44):

Suppose $f: \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ is analytic near $a \in \mathbf{C}$. Geometrically, this can be interpreted as saying that the effect of $f$ on a small vector $h$ emanating from $a$ is just multiplication by the complex number $f'(a)$: $$ f(a+h) \approx f(a) +f'(a)h,$$ where the error tends to zero sublinearly as $|h| \rightarrow 0$. That is, the local effect of an analytic function is a rotation plus a scaling. (There's an equivalent interpretation of the real derivative.)

[image]

In general, if we multiply $z = x + iy$ by a fixed complex number $a + ib$, we have

$$(x + iy) \mapsto (a +ib)(x+iy) =(ax-by) + i(bx+ay).$$

Thinking of $\mathbf{C}$ as $\mathbf{R}^2$, this transformation corresponds to the matrix multiplication
$$ \begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ax - by\\bx+ay\end{bmatrix}.$$

Notice the form of this matrix - it's the composition of a dilation and a rotation about the origin.

Back in $\mathbf{C}$, if $u$ and $v$ are continuously differentiable mappings from $\mathbf{R}^2$ into $\mathbf{R}$, then the Jacobian $J$ of $f = u + iv$ is

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} .$$

$J$ describes the local effect of $f$. Now, for $f$ to be analytic, the Cauchy-Riemann equations require that $u$ and $v$ satisfy $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$  and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $. But if that's true, then $J$ must be a dilative rotation, like the matrix above. So the Cauchy-Riemann equations express the fact that the local effect of an analytic mapping is a dilative rotation, that is, multiplication by a complex number.

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: @Owen Like it +1. Maybe add something akin to the figure 1. on page 2 of this [document](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-366-random-walks-and-diffusion-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lec17_06.pdf).
Just so people have a visual indication (in this case for a conformal mapping whose prerequisite is the fulfillment of the Cauchy-Riemann equations).

Comment: @Kurtovic Good idea. (Picture taken from Tristan Needham, Visual Complex Analysis, pg 196.)

Answer (score 10):

The version of the Cauchy-Riemann equations that I prefer is (assuming we are using $x,y$ as coordinates for the real and imaginary part on the domain)
$$
i\partial_x f = \partial_y f
$$

This has a direct geometrical interpretation: the partial derivative with respect to the real part rotated by $\pi/2$ (which is what multiplying by $i$ does to a complex number) is the partial derivative with respect to the imaginary part.

The geometric interpretation of the complex derivative itself
$$
f(z+h) = f(z) + f'(z)h + o(h)
$$
is that $f$ can be approximated at the first order near $z$ by an affine transformation with a linear part represented by complex multiplication. If $f'(z)=re^{i\theta}$, then $h\mapsto f'(z)h$ is a rotation by $\theta$ followed (or preceded) by a uniform scaling of factor $r$.

This is much more restrictive than *real* differentiability for functions $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, which allows approximation by *arbitrary* affine transformations. For example the mapping $c: (x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)$ has itself as a real differential everywhere (because it's a linear transformation). Geometrically $c$ is a reflection, which changes the orientation of the plane (it sends the base $(1, 0),\ (0, 1)$ which is clockwise or anticlockwise oriented depending on how you draw the axes, to $(1, 0),\ (0, -1)$ which has the opposite orientation). When thought of as a transformation of the complex plane, $c$ is just the complex conjugation $z \mapsto \overline z$. From a geometric viewpoint $c$ has no complex derivative anywhere because if such a derivative $c'(z)$ existed the linear transformation $h\mapsto c'(z)h$ would have to be a reflection, which is impossible to obtain by composing uniform scalings with rotations.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations can be seen as a consequence of the relation between the complex derivative and the real differential. Because of the approximation argument given above and the unicity of the real differential, the complex linear transformation $h\mapsto f'(z)\cdot h$ in $\mathbb C$ corresponds in $\mathbb R^2$ to the real differential
$$
  df(z_x, z_y): \begin{bmatrix}h_x\\h_y\end{bmatrix}\mapsto 
  \begin{bmatrix}\partial_x f(z_x, z_y) & \partial_y f(z_x, z_y)\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}h_x\\h_y\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the real partial derivatives $\partial_x f(z_x, z_y)$ and $\partial_y f(z_x, z_y)$ are column vectors and correspond to the complex partial derivatives $\partial_x f(z), \partial_y f(z)$. Taking $h = 1$, i.e. $h_x = 1, h_y = 0$, in $\mathbb R^2$ we have
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}\partial_x f(z_x, z_y) & \partial_y f(z_x, z_y)\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}\partial_x f(z_x, z_y)\end{bmatrix}
$$

which translated back to $\mathbb C$ is $f'(z)\cdot 1 = \partial_x f(z)$. Taking $h = i$ (i.e. $h_x = 0, h_y = 1$) yields $f'(z)\cdot i = \partial_y f(z)$. Together these two identities give the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\partial_y f(z) = if'(z) = i\partial_x f(z)$.

Comment: Great post, what do you mean by the linear part can change the orientation of the plane? And where is $f'(z) \cdot 1 = \partial_x f(z)$ coming from?

Comment: Thanks @csss. I should probably edit the post to clarify those two points.

Comment: Added a couple of paragraphs, hope it helps

Comment: ...does a rotation by 180 degress not equal a reflection?

Comment: @eurocoder, no. For example think of a clockwise circular arrow, you can rotate it in any way you like (180 deg included), it will still be clockwise. After a reflection it will be anticlockwise

Answer (score 8):

If functions $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations then theirs gradients are orthogonal and equal in length: $\nabla u  \perp \nabla v$, $|\nabla u|=|\nabla v|$. And this means that level curves of $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal where the gradients do not vanish.

Comment: Thank you. And why do these conditions need to be fulfilled for a function to be differentiable?

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out in the comments, there is indeed a nice geometric interpretation in Tristan Needham's ["Visual Complex Analysis"](http://www.amazon.ca/Visual-Complex-Analysis-Tristan-Needham/dp/0198534469). See, especially, the material on the "Polya Vector field". In case you cannot access that book, I've thrown in some point form notes below.

- Let $f = u + iv$ be a complex-valued function, defined on some open domain $D \subset \mathbb{C}$.
- If we identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ via $(x,y) \mapsto x+iy$, then we can think of $f = (u,v)$ as a vector field on $D$.
- The **Polya vector field** $V$ of $f$ is the the complex conjugate $\overline f$, viewed as a vector field. To be precise, $V = (u, -v)$. Obviously, $V$ is completely equivalent to $f$ i.e. $f$ determines $V$ and vice versa. For convenience, let us make notation for the component functions of the $V$. I'll put $P=u$ and $Q = -v$, so as to have  $$V=(P,Q).$$
- The Cauchy-Riemann equations are:
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} && && &&  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.
  \end{align*}
  In terms of $P = u$ and $Q = -v$, that is
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial P}{\partial P} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} =0 && && && \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} =0
  \end{align*}
  which says precisely
  \begin{align*}
  \mathrm{Div}(V) = 0 && && && \mathrm{Curl}(V) = 0,
  \end{align*}
  in terms of the [divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Application_in_Cartesian_coordinates) and [curl](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/3.-double-integrals-and-line-integrals-in-the-plane/part-b-vector-fields-and-line-integrals/session-64-curl/MIT18_02SC_notes_33.pdf) operators.

> **Summary:**
>
> - The first Cauchy Riemann equation says exactly that $\overline f$, when viewed as a vector field, has zero divergence. Some people would say "$\overline f$ is solenoidel".
> - The second Cauchy-Riemann equation says exactly that $\overline f$, when viewed as a vector field, has zero curl. Some people would say "$\overline f$ is irrotational".
>
> Thus, understanding the geometry of the Cauchy-Riemann equations really comes down to understanding the geometry of the divergence and curl operators, whose physical interpretations are [well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) [documented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: As a note, the Polya vector field can be derived formally. Consider the clifford algebra $\mathbb G^2$ that is built upon $\mathbb R^2$.  The even subalgebra of $\mathbb G^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.  Multiplying elements of this subalgebra with any single vector under the clifford product produces a vector result. For the right choice vector to multiply with, you get the Polya vector field and derive the vector calculus analogues of the CR condition.

Answer (score 6):

I personally think of Cauchy Riemann equations in terms of differential geometry.

A function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C $ can be thought of as a function from $\mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, say $f= (u(x,y) , v(x,y))$. Now conformality, (for local diffeomorphisms) is ensured by the fact that First Fundamental form of any surface patch $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{R} ^2$ (say identity function) and First Fundamental form of the patch $f \circ \sigma$ is a scalar multiple of each other.

Lets take $\sigma = id$. First Fundamental form of $\sigma$ is $(1,0,1)$.

Now First Fundamental form of $f \circ \sigma$ is $\left( (u_x^2 + v_x^2), u_x u_y + v_x v_y, (u_y ^2 + v_y^2) \right)$.

So for conformality what we need is $u_x ^2  + v_x ^2 = u_y^2 + v_y ^2$ and $u_xu_y + v_xv_y = 0$.

Note that Cauchy-Riemann equation guarantees that and in fact those equations offer the cauchy-riemann equation(with extra assumption that orientation of angles must also be preserved).

Answer (score 3):

One might think that being differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is sufficient for differentiability on $\mathbb{C}$. But the Jacobian of an arbitrary such function doesn't have a natural complex number representation.

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\partial u/\partial x} & {\partial u/\partial y} \\
{\partial v/\partial x} & {\partial v/\partial y}
\end{array}} \right]
$$

Another way of putting this is that no complex-valued derivative (see below for an example) you can define for an arbitrary function fully captures the local behaviour of the function that is represented by the Jacobian.

$$
\frac{df}{dz} = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right) + i\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)
$$

The idea is that we should be able to define a complex-valued derivative "purely" for the value $z$, without considering directions, i.e. we want to consider $\mathbb{C}$ one-dimensional in some sense (the sense being "as a vector space"). More precisely, the derivative in some direction in $\mathbb{C}$ should determine the derivative in all other directions in a natural manner -- whereas on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the derivatives in *two* directions (i.e. the gradient) determines the directional derivatives in all directions.

If you think about it, this is quite a reasonable idea -- it's analogous to how not every linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear transformation on $\mathbb{C}$ -- only spiral transformations are.

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{a} & {-b} \\
{b} & {a}
\end{array}} \right]
$$

How would we generalise differentiability to an arbitrary manifold? Here's an idea: **a function is differentiable if it is locally a linear transformation**. So on $\mathbb{R}^2$, any Jacobian matrix is a linear transformation.  But on $\mathbb{C}$, only Jacobians of the above form are linear transformations -- i.e. the only linear transformation on $\mathbb{C}$ is **multiplication by a complex number**, i.e. a spiral/amplitwist.  So a complex differentiable function is one that is locally an amplitwist (geometrically), which can be stated in terms of the components of the Jacobian as:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
\end{align}
$$

This is precisely why you shouldn't (and can't) view complex differentiability as some basic first-degree smoothness -- there is a much richer structure to these functions, and it's better to think of them via the transformations they have on grids.

Answer (score -1):

Example of action of a derivative of complex functions. If f(z)=z^2, f'(z)=2z.
For example, at z=1+i, the derivative is f'(1+i)=2(1+i). So if you apply this to something like 0.01, a differential along the horizontal axis in the complex plane, you get 
2(i+1)(0.01)=0.02(1+i)=0.02+0.02i. The "2" in 2(i+1) stretches 0.01 and the 1+i turns it 45 degrees, since 0.02/0.02=1 and arctan(1)=45 degrees.  So you can approximate (1.01+i)^2 as 
(1+i)^2+2(i+1)(0.01) as a first step. This has the form f(z)+f'(z)dz roughly speaking. Or in words, value of function+amplitwist * differential. (Amplitwist is from Visual Complex Analysis by Needham)